# Is there a way to move a window without the mouse?

Tags: macos, keyboard, mouse, x11, xquartz

Since installing Mavericks whenever I open a new window in XQuartz (say gvim) it positions the newly created window at the top left of my monitor.  Because every monitor now has a menu bar, the menu bar covers the title bar of the new window.

This means I can't use my mouse to grab the title bar and drag the window to a new position.

Are there any ways to drag a window using the keyboard, or failing that a way to click on any part of a window to start a drag operation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I upgraded Xquartz and the problem went away.  Windows open below the osx title bar now instead of underneath it.

Answer (score 0):

There is an option in Mavericks to turn off the menu bar on the second screen. Don't have a Mac at work, so perhaps someone could supply exactly where...

Also some help might be found here on arranging windows

https://superuser.com/questions/331/reset-mac-os-x-windows-position-after-de-attaching-external-monitor

Looks like some good tips and Applescripts for doing what you are looking for

Answer (score 0):

Try running scripts like this in AppleScript Editor:

```
tell application "System Events" to tell process "ApplicationName"
    set position of windows to {55, 55}
end tell
```

```
tell application "ApplicationName"
    set bounds of windows to {55, 55, 555, 555}
end tell
```

Some windows can also be moved by for example dragging them horizontally from the bottom edge.

Comment: I tried both those scripts along with another script I had for moving all windows to the primary display.  Unfortunately, XQuartz/X11.bin don't seem to respond to those commands.  XQuartz reports 0 windows open even though there are many windows open.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a third party app such as MercuryMover (many others exist). It will allow you to move windows using the keyboard only.

Answer (score 0):

In the Menu for the program you want to reposition - Go to File/ Close all windows/ then reopen the new window and it positions correctly whether you have just the computer or the second monitor attached.